# How to insert ID to another time (ID is Primary Key)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make attendance software.  I have a table like this:

```
ID       | time present  | date               |
0000001  | 07.00         | january, 1, 2014   |
```

If I enter this value cannot inserted in table because `ID` is primary key:

```
0000001      | 07.00                 | january, 2, 2014   |
```

I need my table can insert current id but different on datetime value like this :

```
0000001 | 07.00  | january, 1, 2014 |
0000001 | 07.15  | january, 2, 2014 |
```

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you adding it in your database or in your application only?

Comment: The definition of primary key means it cannot have a duplicate. Why do you want to insert one?

Answer (score 1):

ID column shouldn't be primery key. Is it maybe atendees id? Rename it accordingly.
Then add another PK, maybe identity.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming id is the primary key, you need to add additional keys to your table. You should add a secondary key such as item count and it would be 0, 1, 2, 3... for each additional item with the same ID.

```
ID       Item Count
0000001 | 0 | 07.00 | january, 1, 2014 |
0000001 | 1 | 07.15 | january, 2, 2014 |
```

Here is the full example 
Table create script

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestExample](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimePresent] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestExample] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [ItemCount] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Insert SQL statements

```
  Insert into [TestExample] (ID, ItemCount, TimePresent, Date)  
  values ( 1, 1, '7:00', '2013-01-01'), 
         ( 1, 2, '7:15', '2013-01-01')
```

Comment: your answer is interest can you give me tutorial please

Answer (score 0):

easy !!!
what you have to do is to make a composite primary key. And since the value of the present time changes but the ID does not, you have to add the present time to the existed primary key, then the ID and present time will be the composite primary key